# Jail movie with cameras installed behind prisoners' eyes; they escape using a blind prisoner

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to find an old movie, it's about a prison where prisoners have cameras installed behind their eyes to be watched, the only scene I remember is about them using a blind prisoner who did not have cameras, to build a device to help their escape.

Comment: My first thought was Fortress 1992, I could have sworn that was the plot but I don't see mention of a blind prisoner in the summary so perhaps I am conflating it with the movie you are looking for.